# Bootstrap dropdown item in navbar not showing DIV after clicking href=#

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I created a navbar with tabs. I can click the tabs and show the content of a . I also created a dropdown in the same navbar. Click on a item in the dropdown list doesn't work.

I checked several examples, but in those examples it is working either (at least for me).

Working example: http://www.live-military-mode-s.eu/mobile/index.php
For example GMT Tab is working. Dropdown, item Action is not working.

Any idea's?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <title>Live Military Mode-s</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport"  content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-responsive.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script>
      
<style type="text/css">
            .navbar-collapse.in {
 overflow-y: visible;
}

body {
    margin: 10px;
}
        </style>

<script type="text/javascript">  
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#myButton").click(function(){

var mytime= new Date().getTime();
var str="test";
    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else { 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("sectionHome").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }


 xmlhttp.open("GET","gmt_2.php",true);

        xmlhttp.send();
    }



    });
});   
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#myTab li:eq(25)").tab('show');
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
<div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" 
         data-target="#example-navbar-collapse">
         <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>

      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span>  Home</a>
   </div>
  
 <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="example-navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
         <li> <a data-toggle="tab" href="#sectionA">GMT</a></li>
         <li> <a data-toggle="tab" href="#sectionB">North America</a></li>
         <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#sectionD">Latin America</a></li>

<li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#sectionA">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>

<li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="true">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">


            <li><a href="#sectionA">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>

      </ul>
   </div>
   </div>
</nav>






<div class="tab-content">
        <div id="sectionHome" class="tab-pane fade in active" >
  <div class="container-fluid">
  <center><img src="image/lmms (2).png"  class="img-responsive" alt="button LMMS">


<p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p>

<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-6">
  <button name="button" id="myButton" class="btn btn-info btn-responsive btn-lg" > How to Join</button>
   <button class="btn btn-info btn-responsive btn-lg">Contact</button>
  <button class="btn btn-info btn-responsive btn-lg">Forum</button>




                   <button class="btn btn-info btn-responsive btn-lg">Log Files</button>
                          <button class="btn btn-info btn-responsive btn-lg">Locations Online</button>
                           <button class="btn btn-info btn-responsive btn-lg">Public Pages</button>




                           <button class="btn btn-info btn-responsive btn-lg">Search</button>
                                   <button class="btn btn-info btn-responsive btn-lg">Unkown Codes</button>
               
                   <button class="btn btn-info btn-responsive btn-lg">Top 10 Pages</button>
</div>
</div>



<p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><script type="text/javascript"><!--
google_ad_client = "pub-3270342864423806";
google_ad_width = 728;
google_ad_height = 90;
google_ad_format = "728x90_as";
google_ad_type = "text_image";
google_ad_channel ="";
//--></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js"><p>
</script>
</center>    
  </div> <!-- /container -->


<div id="footer">
      <div class="container">
        <p class="muted credit">






<Center>542</Center>


</p>
      </div>
</div>
</div>





        <div id="sectionA" class="tab-pane fade">
            <h3>GMT Military mode-s logs</h3>
            <p><button class="btn btn-primary btn-responsive">All others</button></p>
            <p><button class="btn btn-primary btn-responsive">North America</button></p>
            <p><button class="btn btn-primary btn-responsive">Latin America</button></p>
        </div>

        <div id="sectionB" class="tab-pane fade">
            <h3>Section B</h3>
            <p>Vestibulum nec erat eu nulla rhoncus fringilla ut non neque. Vivamus nibh urna, ornare id gravida ut, mollis a magna. Aliquam porttitor condimentum nisi, eu viverra ipsum porta ut. Nam hendrerit bibendum turpis, sed molestie mi fermentum id. Aenean volutpat velit sem. Sed consequat ante in rutrum convallis. Nunc facilisis leo at faucibus adipiscing.</p>
        </div>

        <div id="dropdown1" class="tab-pane fade">
            <h3>Dropdown 1</h3>
            <p>WInteger convallis, nulla in sollicitudin placerat, ligula enim auctor lectus, in mollis diam dolor at lorem. Sed bibendum nibh sit amet dictum feugiat. Vivamus arcu sem, cursus a feugiat ut, iaculis at erat. Donec vehicula at ligula vitae venenatis. Sed nunc nulla, vehicula non porttitor in, pharetra et dolor. Fusce nec velit velit. Pellentesque consectetur eros.</p>
        </div>


        <div id="dropdown2" class="tab-pane fade">
            <h3>Dropdown 2</h3>
            <p>Donec vel placerat quam, ut euismod risus. Sed a mi suscipit, elementum sem a, hendrerit velit. Donec at erat magna. Sed dignissim orci nec eleifend egestas. Donec eget mi consequat massa vestibulum laoreet. Mauris et ultrices nulla, malesuada volutpat ante. Fusce ut orci lorem. Donec molestie libero in tempus imperdiet. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient.</p>
        </div>

    </div>


</div><!-- /container -->


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: All of your links just have a # sign. What are you expecting it to do?

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at the links closer of the ones that are working

```
<a data-toggle="tab" href="#sectionA">
```

You just need to add the appropriate `data-toggle` attribute to your dropdown menu.